# In Golang,why can't I compare []"k8s.io/api/core/v1".ServicePort?

Tags: go

```
newService := serviceforgrafana(grafana)
    if checkservice.Spec != newService.Spec {
        checkservice.Spec = newService.Spec
        if err := r.Update(context.TODO(), checkservice); err != nil {
            return ctrl.Result{}, err
        }
    }
```

newService and checkservice are both corev1.service{}.

controllers/grafana_controller.go:122:23: invalid operation: checkservice.Spec != newService.Spec (struct containing []"k8s.io/api/core/v1".ServicePort cannot be compared)

Comment: this is a great opportunity to write a minimal verifiable example.  This is a pure golang question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structures containing maps or slices are not comparable:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators

You have to compare those manually, or use `reflect.DeepEqual`